# Change the favicon of the Sphinx Read The Docs theme?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm already using a custom css to override some of the styles of the theme using

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_css_file('custom.css')
```

This works fine. What other app. functions are available?
I can't find any documentation.

I'm looking for the function to override the favicon.

Comment: It's in your theme's template. You can override theme files.

Comment: Thanks @StevePiercy for your reply. Can you show me how I can override theme files? Or do I need to download the full theme and make a custom version? I would like to avoid that.

Comment: It depends on the theme. For both included and installable themes, [SO has many posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-sphinx%5D+custom+theme) or consult [Sphinx docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/theming.html).

Answer (score 38):

Thanks to @StevePiercy I found this documentation: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_favicon

**conf.py**

```
html_favicon = 'favicon.ico'
```

I put `favicon.ico` in my `source` folder, next to my `.rst`-files and it is working as expected:
https://global-coffee-data-standard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Edited to `.ico` file extension. it failed with png

Comment: For me, a file called `favicon.png` worked perfectly fine. Not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: In the root folder of the project?  Or the docs/ folder?

Comment: This doesn't work for me on github.io but works locally :/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sphinx's native favicon support (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_favicon), you can also use this Sphinx extension I created: https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-favicon/ With this extension, you can add multiple favicons, including `apple-touch-icon` and icons of different sizes. You can also use PNG or other supported file types.